# Selenium/Python/Chrome/Chrome Dev Tools - Why does the source code and dev tools show 2 different code?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome, I am using LogMeIn to remote to other computers for my job. I log in to my account, and scroll down to the computer I want to use. I am actually trying to set up an automated task using Selenium with Python, so I look at the source code to find the name of the link I want to open. First, the main page source code shows that there is an iframe named "IFrameInCenterPanel". In my code I switch to that iframe. Then I use

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "<computer name>")
```

The element cannot be found. In Chrome, I right click where in that iframe is and view source code, the source code does not have any of the computer names listed their. Below I pasted a redacted version of the dictionary(?) because it is over 100 lines, and the only one I actually need is "FileManager" and/or "GoToFileman" so I can go start setting my task up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var ML = function (ML) {
ML.MYC = {
CancelNote:"Cancel",
CollapseAll:"Collapse All",
Computer:"Computer",
ComputersLCase:"computers",
Computer1:"1 computer",
Computer2:"2 computers",
ComputerProperties:"Computer Properties",
ConnectToThisComp:"Connect to this Computer",
Dashboard:"Dashboard",
DefaultGroup:"Default Group",
BreakAndFixGroupName:"Ad Hoc Support Sessions",
Description:"Description",
DetailView:"Detail View",
DirectConnect:"Direct Connect",
EditLCase:"edit",
ExpandAll:"Expand All",
FileManager:"File Manager",
Filters:"Filters",
ForXDays:"for %d days",
GoToDash:"Go to the dashboard",
GoToFileman:"Go to the file manager",
GoToMainMenu:"Go to the main menu",
Menu:"Menu",
MainMenu:"Main Menu",
MyComputers:"My Computers",
NoComputersInGroup:"No computers in group",
Note:"Note",
};
return ML;
} (ML || {});
//]]>
</script>
```

On the list of computers, to the right of each computer there is a "File Manager" link, when I right click on computer name and select inspect, the Developer Tools panel opens up and highlights the following code:

```
<li id="item#########"" class="tilerow" style="top: 4234px; left: 0px;">
    <div class="online tilerow ">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <div class="cell c1 spr"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="cell c2">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="name inliner">COMPUTER NAME I WANT TO FIND</a> == $0
```

*NOTE: I redacted the item number because I wasn't sure if that was going to be something that was a private thing or not.

And when I inspect the "File Manager" link,  this is the code it highlights:

```
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"> == $0
                "File Manager"
                <div class="icon spr fileman"></div>
            </a>
```

The code that I have been using:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("IFrameInCenterPanel"))
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "computer name").click()
```

returns that the link text cannot be found. For now I just want to get to the link for the computer itself. But I would eventually like to just click file manager. If anyone can help me with this, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don’t know where to begin. I tried that and this where I ended up.